# Alternative to niceload command in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, paging, parallel-processing, gnu, ulimit

I'm looking for some alternative to [niceload](http://www.gnu.org/s/parallel/niceload.html) utility in Ubuntu. Is there some utility like niceload that is easily available (apt-get install ...) in that distribution ?

To be more specific I've ran into a problem when running several (8) number crunching processes on my box. Occasionally one of these processes requires a lot of memory (~10Gb, for a few minutes). System have only 24Gb of memory. So I need something to prevent more than two processes simultaneously running in that 'high memory load' mode. Otherwise I'm running into very heavy swapping and system pretty much freezes.

It looks like [niceload](http://www.gnu.org/s/parallel/niceload.html) utility would do the trick, but it is not supereasy to install in Ubuntu (it is part of the GNU Parallel). Is there some alternative in Ubuntu that is readily available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Ubuntu package of GNU Parallel here:
https://build.opensuse.org/package/binaries?package=parallel&project=home%3Atange&repository=xUbuntu_10.04

The new release has `--start-mem` and `--noswap` which seems to be exactly what you are looking for.